# How To Control Woo-Commerce JSON API DATA?

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

Right now , I am working on a project. I have to build some rest full api's for android application using Woo-Commerce CLIENT REST API.

Everything is working fine, but the data i'm getting is unnecessary. So can anybody tell me, how to overcome from this problem.

e.g. I am getting this data

```js
{
product_categories: [
{
id: 8,
name: "Cakes",
slug: "cakes",
parent: 0,
description: "Love is like a good cake; you never know when it's coming, but you'd better eat it when it does!",
count: 11
},
{
id: 9,
name: "Breads",
slug: "breads",
parent: 0,
description: "All sorrows are less with bread. ",
count: 3
},
{
id: 10,
name: "Pastries",
slug: "pastries",
parent: 0,
description: "I'm not a vegetarian! I'm a pastries-ian!",
count: 6
}
```

but i do not want slug,parent, description parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this link helps you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: I want to do it from server side. There are lots of unnecessary parameters , to remove like this is huge headache.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problems is `" "` missing in key `Ex: "ID", "name"` and
You use this function `json_pretty()` for json format.

```
function json_pretty($json, $html = false) {
    $out = ''; $nl = "\n"; $cnt = 0; $tab = 4; $len = strlen($json); $space = ' ';
    if($html) {
        $space = '&nbsp;';
        $nl = '<, $html = false)br/>';
    }
    $k = strlen($space)?strlen($space):1;
    for ($i=0; $i<=$len; $i++) {
        $char = substr($json, $i, 1);
        if($char == '}' || $char == ']') {
            $cnt --;
            $out .= $nl . str_pad('', ($tab * $cnt * $k), $space);
        } else if($char == '{' || $char == '[') {
            $cnt ++;
        }
        $out .= $char;
        if($char == ',' || $char == '{' || $char == '[') {
            $out .= $nl . str_pad('', ($tab * $cnt * $k), $space);
        }
    }
    return $out;    
}
```

> How to user this function ?

```
$pre = '{"status": 1,"message": "My Collection downloaded successfully.","myCollections":';     
$postd = ' }';  
$jsa_data = json_encode($res_arr); // pass your Array
echo $finalJson = json_pretty($pre.$jsa_data.$postd);
```

> Out put

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "All Post downloaded successfully",
    "postData": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Cakes",
            "slug": "cakes",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "Love is like a good cake; you never know when it's coming, but you'd better eat it when it does!",
            "count": 11
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Breads",
            "slug": "breads",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "All sorrows are less with bread. ",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Pastries",
            "slug": "pastries",
            "parent": 0,
            "description": "I'm not a vegetarian! I'm a pastries-ian!",
            "count": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

> Check it Json LINT http://jsonlint.com/